# Exported model (done with cloud generator a-o) not showing probably

Tags: export, add-on

I am new to 3D design; and all my experience is with programming.
I used blender cloud generator add-on to produce a cloud, then exported it in (.dae) format. Instead of a cloud; I'm getting the raw shape only.

i.e if my cloud is composed of metaballs, the metaballs appear only.
Destination is Three.js project.

Screenshots:
-Blender:
[image]

-Imported Output in javascript:
[image]

Comment: Simulations and effects are not exportable, in collada or any other format. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you very much for your feedback; saved me a lot of time